# Delete head element from queue

Tags: c, queue

I have declare a struct like below:

```
struct example
{
      // some element here
      struct example *next;
};
struct example *head;
```

Suppose I have alredy made a queue from "example" struct and now I want to move out the head element (surely, after move first element in queue out I have to delete it out of queue). I have delete code like this:

```
void delete()
{
    struct example *temp = malloc (sizeof(struct example) * 1);
    temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

And my question is function "delete" do the jobs:

1. Delete first element in queue and make next element be head of new queue

or 2. It's not delete first element in queue but make head = head->next and delete "temp" pointer and "the old head" still exist somewhere

Comment: What does your question have to do with hyperlinks?

Comment: Ah, sorry for that mistake, I have already edited, thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in fact appropriately setting `head` to the next item in the queue **and** deleting the old head. *However*, for what appears to be no reason, you are using `malloc()` to create memory which you then lose the only pointer to when you overwrite `temp` on the next line. You should initialize `temp` to `head`. There is no need to `malloc()` memory in a `delete()` function. If you did need `malloc()`, note that `* 1` is redundant and unnecessary.

Also, what will happen if your queue is empty and `head` is `NULL`? Think about that.

Whether your queue will work or not remains to be seen since you will also need a `tail` pointer to know where to add new items to the queue.

Additionally, I would avoid naming functions `delete()` since it may be confused for the C++ keyword `delete`. `remove()` would be more appropriate.